# Using JSON to Serialize/Deserialize TimeSpan

Tags: c#, json, web-services, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize/serialize a timespan with [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm), but when the JSON is sent it's set to 00:00:00.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Which serializer you use? JavaScriptSerializer? DataContractJsonSerializer? Could you post a small code example which not work?

Comment: I use Newtonsoft.json.jsonconvert. 

So what i do is.

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TimeSpan);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, Apparently it's a MS design flaw...

Since TimeSpan cannot be a parameterless object. XML cannot recreate it.

Take a look at this website.
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/51793/135450.aspx

So. Therefore TimeSpan cannot be converted. An easy way to do this is
to change the timespan into a string, and then send the string over.
and use TimeSpan.TryParse(String);

Comment: What does XML have to do with your question?

Comment: @Crisfole I think instead of "XML", he's referring to whatever serializer he's using (a lot of them serialize to both XML and JSON).

Answer (score 15):

I tried #Jessycormier's method and it didn't work for me.
I ran DataContractJsonSerializer to see what it would generate and I found that gave me a value that looked more like this.

```
{"PassedTimeSpan":"P1DT2H3M4S"}
```

The value shown above was for 1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes, and 4 seconds.

So it looks like format is:

> [-]P[{days}D][T[{hours}H][{min}M][{sec}S]]

Where:

> - Indicates negative timespan, omitted for positive values
>   P must be the first character (unless negative time value)
>   T must precede the time portion of the timespan. 
>   [] = optional part that may be omitted if 0.

Comment: Thanks for writing down the generic template! Based on this, I could write the next function: formatTime = function (jsonTime) {
        var re = /-?P(?:\d+D)?(?:T(?:(\d+)H)?((\d+)M)?((\d+)S)?)?/;
        var timeArray = re.exec(jsonTime);
        var h = timeArray[1] == undefined ? "" : timeArray[1];
        var hr = "00" + h;
        var hour = hr.substr(hr.length - 2, 2);
        var m = timeArray[2] == undefined ? "" : timeArray[2];
        var min = "00" + m;
        var minute = min.substr(min.length - 2, 2);
        return hour + ":" + minute;
    }

Comment: It return me `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.TimeSpan' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.`

Comment: @egoPinvina Try DataContractJsonSerializer

Answer (score 5):

If you apply the exact format you can use a TimeSpan. The format is: "0.00:00:00.0000"

Setting a TimeSpan to 30 minutes

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
    myDataObject: {
         TimeSpanValue : "0.00:" + $("#InputWithMinVal").val() + ":00.0"
    }
});
```

This solution works for me. I'm using MVC 4.0 with .Net framework 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

These answers are all outdated, so I thought I would provide an updated better answer. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) now directly supports .NET `Timespan` serialization format.

As of version 2.1.0, this is supported:

```
moment.duration('23:59:59');
moment.duration('23:59:59.999');
moment.duration('7.23:59:59.999');
moment.duration('23:59'); // added in 2.3.0
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of moment.js or any javascript in this.