# How can I map the timestamp

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have a problem that one property can not be mapped to entity when passing a json from client to bakend. This is my model I received as the parameter.

```
public class Utnker
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    ...
    public TimeSpan time { get; set; }
}
```

When I use a string to pass the time, it can not trigger the bakend.

```
let Data = {
  'Property':'b',
  'time':'10.12:6:8'
};
fetch('', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(Data)
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

When I use the local json converter to convert the json, it can get the expected result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Json to Serialize/Deserialize TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232701/using-json-to-serialize-deserialize-timespan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use newtonsoft to convert the json. But if you do not want to use the plugin, you can customize a jsonconverter.

```
public class TimeSpanConverter : JsonConverter<TimeSpan>
{
  public override TimeSpan Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
  {
    return TimeSpan.Parse(reader.GetString());
  }
  public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TimeSpan value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
  {
    writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
  }
}
```

Then register it in startup.

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new TimeSpanConverter())

);
```