# Can't set TimeSpan property from JSON source C#

Tags: c#, json, timespan

I have been trying to read a JSON file and deserialize it to a class object. The problem is that I am storing a `TimeSpan?` property of the class as `string` in the JSON file which doesn't get deserialized and remains null. Please find the code for reference below:

Interface:

```
public interface IAirport
{
  .
  .
  .
  TimeSpan? TimeOffset { get; set; }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Class :

```
public class Airport:IAirport{
  .
  .
  .
  private TimeSpan? _offsetTime;
  public TimeSpan? OffssetTime
  {
    get{return _offsetTime;}
    set{SetProperty<TimeSpan>(ref _offsetTime, value);}
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

This is the way I deserialize :

```
private static T ConvertJsonStreamToObject<T>(StreamReader fileStream)
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream, typeof(T));
        }
```

and lastly the JSON :

```
{
    "AirportDesignation": "ZZU",
    "EffectiveDate": "1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000",
    "Description": "Mzuzu",
    "DescriptionShort": "Mzuzu",
    "EffectiveStatus": "A",
    "Country": "MWI",
    "State": " ",
    "LatitudeDegrees": 11,
    "LatitudeMinutes": 27,
    "LatitudeSeconds": 0,
    "LatitudeCoordinates": "S",
    "LongitudeDegrees": 34,
    "LongitudeMinutes": 1,
    "LongitudeSeconds": 0,
    "LongitudeCoordinates": "E",
    "AirportType": "A",
    "TimeOffset": "00:00:00",
    "IsTimeOffsetPositive": true
  }
```

I tried the following way to set the property and use `TimeSpan.Parse()` to parse the `string` to `TimeSpan` but none of them worked :

```
private string _timeOffset;            
public TimeSpan? TimeOffset
{
  get { return TimeSpan.Parse(_timeOffset); }
  set { _timeOffset = value.ToString(); }
}
```

I am out of ideas to try, any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I tried @Caius Jard suggestion, getting the `System.ArgumentNullException`

Updated the property as below:

```
private string _timeOffset;
        [Required]
        public TimeSpan? TimeOffset
        {
            get { return TimeSpan.Parse(_timeOffset); }
            set { SetProperty<string>(ref _timeOffset, value.Value.ToString()); }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232701/using-json-to-serialize-deserialize-timespan

Comment: *I am out of ideas to try* - have a TimeSpan typed property that is `JsonIgnore`. Have a `string` typed property that reads and writes the timespan so the json serializer will use it to read/write strings. Use the timespan typed property in your code

Comment: Why not include the timezone in any DateTime properties that use it and store the underlying UTC value instead of a local date/time and offset separately? E.g. in your JSON payload: `EffectiveDate: "1901-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+0400"`

Comment: The .Net Property name doesn't seem to match the JSON's. Why don't you simply specify the property as `public TimeSpan? TimeOffset { get; set; }`? Then add behavior, eventually. -- With a TimeSpan set to `"00:00:00"`, the property should have  `.TimeOffset.HasValue`  equals to `true` and `.TimeOffset.Value` equals to `00:00:00`.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're using a quite old version of Json.Net. This: `(T)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream, typeof(T));` doesn't currently exist, you have to pass a JsonTextReader initialized from a Stream, then use the `.Deserialize<T>` version. -- Possibly, update your NuGet package.

Comment: Works fine for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/PjoTVB please give a [mcve] with an actual JSON string to deserialize, and also which version of Newtonsoft you are using

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit finally, It was an attribute causing the problem. I had an interface as the base for the `Airport` class and it required the `TimeOffset` to be a `[DataMember]` otherwise the property isn't identified as the data member of the class.
Adding the `[DataMember]` attribute now sets the value.